# How can I format and export PCA output in Stata?

Tags: pca, stata

Are there any tools that can format and write to external file output of principal component analysis in Stata?

I'm thinking about something that will work in similar vein to [excellent] family of [estout](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/index.html) commands.

Comment: You will likely get excellent and authoritative answers to this question on the stata list (http://www.stata.com/statalist/ ).  It is THE place to go with issues about how Stata works.

Comment: i would agree with @whuber but no harm in asking here either. The question is on-topic as far as this site is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) & [Srikant Vadali](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28/srikant-vadali) I posted [this question](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-12/msg00443.html) on Statalist.

[Maarten L. Buis](http://www.maartenbuis.nl/) [pointed](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-12/msg00451.html) that estout itself can be [used](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/advanced.html#advanced404) for processing PCA (as well as factor analysis) results. Thanks Maarten.